# TextView inside ScrollView stick to keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have a `UIScrollView` and content inside it. Inside content there is a `UITextView`. When user presses the `UITextView` I want the `UITextView` stick to the keyboard.

[image]
In the image:
Whole thing is `UIScrollView`
Bottom black area is the visible screen
Red area is content
Blue area is `UITextView`
Green distance is the dynamic margin between content and the screen bound.

I want to calculate the green distance which the user can see along with the blue are(`UITextView`) which the user can see. If the user half swiped `UITextView`, the `UITextView` should still stick to the keyboard.

```
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as UInt
    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as Double

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(curve << 16)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: options,
        animations: {

            var visibleGreen = ???
            var visibleBlue = ???
            var amountToSubtract = visibleGreen + visibleBlue


            var newFrame = (self.currentCardInstance?.newCommentCell.frame)!
            var kbFrameEnd = self.view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame, toView: nil)
            var kbFrameBegin = self.view.convertRect(keyboardBeginFrame, toView: nil)
            newFrame.origin.y -= kbFrameBegin.origin.y - kbFrameEnd.origin.y + amountToSubtract

            self.currentCardInstance?.newCommentCell.frame = newFrame;
        },
        completion: nil
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
var keyboardModifier: CGFloat = 0

func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("keyboardWillAppear")
    keyboardResize(notification: notification)
    scrollToBottom()
}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("keyboardWillDisappear")
    keyboardResize(notification: notification)
}

func keyboardResize(#notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as UInt
    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as Double
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(curve << 16)

    var newFrame = (self. currentCardInstance?.frame)!
    var kbFrameEnd = self.view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame, toView: nil)
    var kbFrameBegin = self.view.convertRect(keyboardBeginFrame, toView: nil)

    keyboardModifier = kbFrameBegin.origin.y - kbFrameEnd.origin.y

    scrollView.frame.size.height -= keyboardModifier
}

func scrollToBottom() {
    var bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)
}
```